# A single quote code symbol (&#39;) is automatically converted by the ASPxHtmlEditor to another code (&apos;)

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress

I am having a problem with the aspxHTMLEditor.
For example “'” is used instead of a single quote. The HTML editor is converting the “'” to “'”. This is a serious problem, I do not want the HTML editor changing my data.

Comment: Which DX version being used? Try view similar issue here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B136514 (confirmed to be a bug, upgrade to later version if necessary).

Comment: I am using 15.2 DX Version.
I had already go through above blog which you have shared over here but it didn't work.